# Getting "best-guess" coordinates from a location name in Python

Tags: python, location, coordinates, geocoding, estimation

I'm looking for a way to take a rough location string (ex. "Buddy's Pub in City, State"), and convert it to the best-guess set of coordinates. I've looked at GeoPy and Google's Geocoding API, but they are not exactly what I'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This repository should be helpful : https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python

Comment: @aminrd Thank you, that is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: This is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile How so?

Comment: Please see: [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it thanks to @aminrd tip.

Google Places API is the answer.

```
import googlemaps
API_KEY = "your google API key goes here"
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=API_KEY)
place_result = gmaps.find_place(input='Buddy\'s Pub in City, State', input_type='textquery', fields=["geometry/location"])
print(place_result)
```

Output looks like

```
{'candidates': [{'geometry': {'location': {'lat': XX.2804533, 'lng': -XXX.1195808}}}], 'status': 'OK'}
```